# Jetty Classpath issues

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I'm currently running Solr out of a Jetty container that it ships with. It runs correctly when run from the command line via:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

when I'm in the same directory as start.jar. Unfortunately I need to be able to launch jetty from any directory, not just the one that contains start.jar. I've tried many options, such as:

```
java  -Dsolr.solr.home=~/solr/ -Djetty.home=~/solr/ -Djetty.logs=~/solr/logs/ -cp ~/solr/start.jar:~/solr/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26-patched-JETTY-1340.jar:~/solr/lib/jetty-6.1.26-patched-JETTY-1340.jar:~/solr/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar -jar ~/solr/start.jar ~/solr/etc/jetty.xml
```

Every  time I get this backtrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:179)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that when you run

```
java  ... -cp ~/solr/start.jar:... -jar ~/solr/start.jar ~/solr/etc/jetty.xml
```

the `-cp` option is ignored since you use the `-jar` option.

From `man java`:

> `-jar`
>
> *When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.*

You have two options:

- Keep using the `-jar` option, but then you need to provide the classpath in the jar manifest file (note that these classpath entries can't be *relative* to the current path, only relative to the jar-file you're executing)
- Skip the `-jar` option and provide the main class explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Simply changing to the correct directory before calling java.... fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I was trying to run it anyhow :). This solved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `~` as a short cut to the current user's home directory. I'd replace all tilde characters with an absolute path and see if that helps.

Comment: That's already done by bash before executing. Try `echo hello ~` and you'll see.

Comment: Wasn't assuming he was always executing from bash. Ubuntu occasionally did (does?) weird things with default shell choices (*dash* vs *bash*, anyone?), and I've had tilde-expansion issues in the past.

Comment: Same for all compatible shells. Read up on tilde expansion in your favorite manual.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in Jan 2014.My issue was that because I ran a Cluster Zookeeper setup from elsewhere, the $SOLR_HOME/lib folder got moved under $SOLR_HOME/cloud-scripts where the zkCli.bat exists.Copied the lib folder back under $SOLR_HOME/ and it works now.